# How to best cut this fallen tree?

Tags: gravity

I have a fallen tree. The root structure is painted dark brown, is nearly perpendicular to the ground and is about 12 feet tall. The main trunk is lighter brown and is supported on the ground by a remaining limb, drawn in yellow:

[image: ![enter image description here]

I want to separate the root structure from the balance of the trunk/limb (as close as possible to the root structure) with a chainsaw.

I am considering the following two options:

1. I make a “fall directional” cut on the top of the trunk structure and a “break” cut on the bottom as follows:

   [image: ![enter image description here]
2. I make the “fall directional” cut on the *bottom* of the trunk and a “break” cut on the top thusly:

   [image: ![enter image description here]

My aim is:

1. to make the root structure fall back to the earth (to the left);
2. to have the trunk/limb to rotate counterclockwise (back to the earth);
3. to not die.

These goals are specifically ordered.

My first thought was to rotate the system almost 90 degrees counterclockwise and pretend that the trunk/limb was falling to the right, so option #2 would be appropriate. Thinking further on it, it occurs to me that the falling portion of the project is the root system, meaning option #1 would be the appropriate answer.

Any answers, humorous or logical, would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE. Your question at best borders the scope of this site (see [this Meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4535/36360)). It is likely on-topic on [gardening.se], and you almost certainly will receive better answers there.

Comment: Keep in mind that here on Stack Exchange we [hate fun](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/) =P. But yeah, [gardening.se] is probably a much better place to ask this.

Comment: I don't really know, but common sense (or what passes for it for a physicist) tells me that Option 1 will jam the blade.

Comment: option 2 could jam the blade also, it depends which direction the flexing force on the trunk is at the point of the cut,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are too many non-physics factors involved (eg plant structure and care) to make the application of physics worthwhile.  As suggested, it would be far more appropriate in a Gardening forum.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft +1 for your sincere, all though be it a most unanswering answer. I was unaware that this was **un**applied physics. The question is most *certainly* a physics one, though, right? Off to Gardening & Landscaping I go.

Comment: @Chowzen: Before re-asking on [gardening.se], consider flagging your question for migration to take the existing answers with you (if you want that). Also, do not hesitate to comment on my answer as to why it was unanswering.

Comment: @count_to_10 Am I being warned not to ask actual Physics Questions?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft the "unanswering" comment was on your comment, not your Answer. Cheers!

Comment: This is not unapplied physics. nor are you prohibited from asking physics questions. The difficulty is that this is not a problem to which physics can give a reliable answer. There are too many other factors to consider. The advice of an experienced gardener is far superior to the opinion of a bunch of theoretical physicists. Does everyone suddenly think that theoretical physics has the answer to every problem, just because Sheldon Cooper is famous? Does nobody remember how few non-physics questions he has answered correctly?

Comment: @sammygerbil Huh. I thought it was about the pictures. The ones de**picting**  a physical question, hypothetically. Who the **** is Sheldon Cooper? I asked  a naked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only make a fall-directional cut if the trunk is vertical, because then the top part of the the tree is (roughly speaking) in an unstable gravitational equilibrium when cut and it can topple to either site. Here details such as the order of cuts makes a difference.

In your case, however, the individual pieces of the cut are far from a gravitational equilibrium and thus the order of cuts does not affect in which direction the pieces fall.

For comparison consider a ball balanced on top of a half-sphere. Here a tiny push can affect in which direction it will roll of the sphere. However, if the ball is not balanced on the top but starts somewhere else, a tiny push hardly matters.

The main thing you should take into consideration is that you do not want to clamp your chainsaw. Depending on how much your components weigh, your trunk (orange) either bends upwards or downwards. You should be able to find out what is actually the case by visual inspection.

- If your trunk bends downwards (like this: ⏝), you do not want to start cutting from the top because it will jam your blade. In this case, your root will fall to the right (unless you use further tools).
- If your trunk bends upwards (like this: ⏜), you do not want to start cutting from the bottom because it will jam your blade. In this case, the whole structure may move considerably while cutting, so be extra careful. For example, the root may fall back to its original position before you finished cutting.

Your trunk will always rotate counter-clockwise.

Either way, be careful where your parts may fall, which parts are under stress and where they may snap.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complicated problem, it is not easily determined what forces are on the roots, and the scale is unclear.

I would make the fall directional cut (or scarf) on the underside of the trunk, and the break cut on the topside, slightly higher (as the tree grew) up the trunk.

I think this is the answer because the roots are likely bound in place by dislocated earth and will not move much (this is based solely on all the toppled stumps I have seen), but the trunk being heavy will tend to fall to the ground.